# How can I run code when a Rails.fire call has completed?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, rails-ujs

I am submitting my form via JavaScript like this

```
Rails.fire(form, 'submit');
```

I would like to run some extra code when it has completed, Is there a way to do that? I suppose I am looking for an onSuccess method or similar.